# Reabrir ou não esta pergunta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, fechamento

Esta pergunta foi fechada como "baseada em opiniões":

[Quais são os principais compiladores para C++14 no Linux?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/281903)

Eu fiz uma outra leitura dela, em forma de pergunta objetiva, e editei a pergunta para dar menos margem a respostas opinativas. Os pontos que eu queria debater são:

1. Essa pergunta deve ser reaberta ou não? Por quê?
2. A resposta atual está com -2. Ela tem problemas técnicos? Ou será que levou os negativos por outros motivos?

Comment: É uma pergunta a respeito de ferramentas de desenvolvimento de software. Não achei baseada em opinião. Acho que poderia reabrir uma pergunta dessa, mas, esse tipo de pergunta tem que ser feita com cuidado, o AP tem que fazer de um jeito que restringe uma resposta opinativa, contextualizar sempre ajuda, [veja um exemplo de pergunta parecida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/27190).

Comment: Quanto a resposta, eu não negative e nem positivei, mas acho que até poderia ser positivada, é minha opinião só. O AR poderia editar e tentar melhorar mais, pode vir a ser útil no futuro.

Comment: Também sinalizo para reabrir, não entendi o que tem a ver com o META

Comment: O cara perguntou, quais são os principais. E mesmo que fosse qual é o melhor, ainda sim existem diferenças evidentes entre compiladores

Comment: @Sveen a palavra **principais** que se tornou o problema. Porque independente de principal, o que realmente o AP quer é um compilador que suporte as novas funcionalidades do C++14.

Comment: A resposta não tem nada errado nem tecnicamente errado. Também não entendi os negativos como coisa técnica, mas como retaliação à pergunta. Após a edição (que não removeu a intenção da pergunta original) ficou evidente a tecnicidade

Comment: @gato o "principal" foi por minha conta, na edição. A intenção era evitar que ficasse ampla.

Comment: @Sveen o Meta StackOverflow PT é o site que existe para discutir coisas que acontecem no site StackOverflow PT. Questionar o fechamento e fazer o pedido de reabertura é uma discussão gerada pelo fato de que o fechamento não foi adequado. Então por isso essa questão veio para o Meta.

Answer (score 7):

A pergunta não é baseada em opiniões, a original ou a edita que melhorou de um lado, piorou de outro porque não define o que é principal.

Dá para questionar se é uma boa pergunta para o formato. Assim como ando discutindo o formato.

Se é para ser aceita eu acho que precisá tratá-la, mas agora com resposta já complica um pouco. Por isso falo que o (nosso) formato não é bom para certas coisas, se ele mudasse um pouco seria mais fácil lidar com essas coisas. Dá para responder bem, mas dá para sair respostas ruins.

A resposta removida é bem ruim. A que ficou é até boa.

[Tem muito compilador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C++_compilers). Até o Visual Studio pode gerar binário para o Linux. a pergunta indica, mas não deixa claro que tudo tem que ser feito no Linux.

Poderia fechar como não clara, mas de que adianta com uma resposta já postada? Vamos negar ter uma pior e também de ter uma melhor. Embora tenha ferramenta atualmente, não usamos para deixar claro que a pergunta/resposta precisa ser lida e interpretada com cuidado.

Faz sentido?

Comment: Faz sentido, penso parecido. Não reparei que estava criando um problema ao usar "principal"; a intenção era dar o sentido de *mainstream* (talvez menos subjetivo?)

Comment: Editei de novo, espero não ter piorado :)

Comment: Levando em consideração o contexto [original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/281903/1) da pergunta, quando o **AP** diz: "***Qual compilador, gratis, posso utilizar...***" da-se a entender que o mesmo necessita de uma **opinião** sobre qual compilador dentre **N** gratuitos ele deve utilizar. Claro que essa é minha opinião.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que a pergunta está bem formulada e deve ser reaberta.

A resposta pode depender de qual funcionalidade do c++14 o autor quer e que versão do centos ele está usando, mas isso não quer dizer que a pergunta é baseada em opnião. O g++5 e o clang++3.4 devem cobrir as funcionalidades que ele está precisando.

Se quiser ser realmente exigente, troque a pergunta para algo como "qual versão do gcc e do clang implementam as funcionalidades do c++14". Mas acho isso um preciosismo.