# baseada em opinião ou não?

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

Fiz uma pergunta no Stack sobre qual seria a melhor distro Linux para usar o Android Studio, acho que removi a pergunta (não lembro já faz um tempo), a pergunta era focada apenas na performance, lembro que pesquisei isso em outros forums porém não achei nada conclusivo (apenas "usa distro tal que tem vários tutoriais"), porém achei um site com comparativo de qual distro seria melhor em algumas aplicações (sobre o Android Studio não)

Porém ela foi fechada justificada por ser baseada em opinião. Queria uma explicação do motivo, não entendo como a opinião de alguém pode aumentar ou diminuir a performance do Android Studio em determinada distribuição Linux?

Comment: Não vi sua pergunta, mas às vezes o título pode levar a um entendimento errado. Se o texto estiver claro que era análise de performance, paciência, erro dos leitores e você veio no canto certo fazer barulho. Uma questão foi fechada recentemente com um motivo muito semelhante, a discussão está rolando: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6872/64969; eu mesmo insatisfeito com outro fechamento abri uma questão sobre ele do mesmo jeito que você fez, expondo o porquê de o fechamento estar errado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6857/64969

Comment: Na verdade quem excluiu sua pergunta foi o robô do site. Segue link para que possamos debater o  caso específico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267486/melhor-distro-linux-para-android-studio (acessível para você e para usuários com 10k+ de pontuação).

Comment: Totalmente baseada em opiniao do jeito que está. E foge completamente do escopo. Achei o fechamento correto.

Comment: Dá sim pra encarar a pergunta de maneira objetiva, respondendo com uma comparação de algumas distros em relação ao Android Studio. Por outro lado, ela tem boas chances de receber respostas opinativas, como a que havia sido postada. Sinceramente, se você não encontrou esse comparativo na internet, acho difícil que alguém se dê ao trabalho de testar o aplicativo em diversas distros para saber qual é mais performática. Talvez você mesmo poderia fazer isso e postar uma resposta :) Isso caso a discussão aqui leve à reversão da exclusão e reabertura.

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo que a pergunta pode levar a muitas respostas baseadas em opiniões, porém marcar uma pergunta como baseada em opinião por que a resposta é baseada em opinião não acho justo. Não tenho como testar isso, sequer tenho um pendrive, recentemente coloquei o linux mint no meu computador, usando um pendrive emprestado, precisaria de pelo menos uma semana para mudar a distro, instalar o o android studio e testar

Comment: @Articuno, por que?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sua pergunta era essa:

> ## Melhor distro linux para android studio
>
> Queria saber qual seria a melhor distro linux para programar no android studio, sei que essa resposta é relativa e envolve bastante a opinião da pessoa, mas qual linux tem a melhor performance no android studio?
>
> Vi alguns sites e peguntas em outros foruns mas nao cheguei numa conclusão e nao achei nenhuma pergunta aqui sobre isso.
>
> Vi comparações de algumas distro linux em certos programas mas o desempenho varia muito de acordo com o programa, e nao mostrava o desempenho no android studio e mesmo assim eram só algumas distros.
>
> Busco apenas desempenho, facilidades e "design" da distro nao fazem diferença
>
> [linux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) [android-studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) [desempenho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/desempenho)

Foi fechada como baseada em opiniões e depois removida automaticamente pelo ["usuário" Comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade). Esse usuário é na verdade um robô que realiza diversas tarefas automáticas no site, dentre as quais a remoção de perguntas consideradas abandonadas.

Há vários critérios que caracterizam as perguntas como abandonadas. No seu caso, foi por a pergunta ter estado **por alguns dias** na seguinte situação:

- Fechada.
- Com votação negativa.
- Sem respostas com pontuação positiva.

Eu considero que o fechamento foi correto:

- Perguntas no estilo "*qual é o melhor*", ainda mais quando há dezenas de opções que poderiam ser consideradas, costumam ser perguntas opinativas.
- Há dezenas de distros por aí, e embora as mais comuns estejam estabelecidas há décadas, elas estão sempre mudando e de vez em quando alguma boa nova distro surge. Só isso já torna a sua pergunta um alvo móvel.
- Performance é algo que pode ser subjetivo, pois há vários tipos de performance. Performance no tempo de compilação? Performance na velocidade de execução? Performance no consumo de CPU? Tempo de resposta da interface do usuário? Consumo de memória? Como é que você avalia a performance de uma IDE? Uma coisa é você definir o que é performance de um programa que realiza um cálculo matemático em matrizes ou em mineração de criptomoedas, o que é quantificável por operações por segundo, hashes por segundo, etc. Outra coisa é definir performance em algo que basicamente é um editor de texto anabolizado que executa scripts por debaixo do pano. Veja mais sobre isso em [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/132).
- Sua pergunta é uma [pergunta XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). A menos que você use uma distro que claramente esteja bem fora da sua finalidade (tais como umas específicas para servidores ou para serem executadas em dispositivos móveis), dificilmente você terá uma diferença mensurável entre o Ubuntu e o Debian, por exemplo. A maior parte das questões de desempenho, qualquer que seja a definição exata de desempenho nesse caso, vão depender muito mais do hardware do que da distro.
- Há também uma forma de considerar desempenho como a produtividade humana do programador ao utilizar o android studio com a distro em questão, e isso depende bastante das facilidades e design, exatamente o que você quer desconsiderar. E nisso também entram fatores psicológicos e sociais de cada um (no caso, de você apenas), algo bastante opinativo e particular e que tende muito mais ao escopo da psicologia do que de programação. Isso reforça que essa pergunta é opinativa, subjetiva e é um problema XY.

Comment: Concordo que faltou deichar mais claro que tipo de performance eu queria. Mas o seu penúltimo tópico (sobre a diferença ser imperceptível) é uma resposta que eu aceitaria para pergunta, e não foi baseada em opinião

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Sim, se a pergunta estivesse aberta, eu poderia até postar uma resposta nela nesse sentido. Mas provavelmente seria uma resposta um tanto frustrante para você, pois quase toda pergunta XY chega a um desfecho frustrante tanto para quem pergunta quanto para quem responde.

Comment: Eu não consideraria frustante, não seria a resposta que eu imaginava mas também não seria frustante

Answer (score 2):

Sendo bem curto, sem adentrar em análises técnicas como fez com muita propriedade nosso amigo **@Victor Stafusa**, apenas o fato do texto da pergunta conter:

> *[...]sei que essa resposta é relativa e envolve bastante a opinião da pessoa.*

Já se auto-condena a fechamento por não observar o que diz a página de [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Nem todas as perguntas funcionam corretamente em nosso formato. Evite
> perguntas que sejam **principalmente baseadas em opiniões** ou que
> provavelmente **gerarão discussões** em lugar de respostas.

Sem mais.

Comment: Essa referencia é porque muitos usuários poderiam dar opiniões baseadas no que eles acham melhor sem sequer ser baseada em performance, mas no final também falo _"[...]Busco apenas desempenho, facilidades e "design" da distro nao fazem diferença"_

Comment: Compreendo o seu interesse em obter uma boa resposta que atenda a pergunta, e até particularmente achei a sua pergunta muito interessante, porém ela se encaixaria mais num fórum de discussão sobre o assunto, que tem um formato bem diferente do SO.

Comment: Seria até bom se o SO abrisse uma margem para esse tipo de discussão.

Comment: Poderia ser aberto um novo site expecificamente para tratar de de discussões relacionadas a programação quem sabe um _pt.talk.stackoverflow.com_

Comment: Seria perfeito se tivesse, quem sabe com a evolução das coisas.

Comment: Ja não existe alguma discussão aqui no meta sobre isso?

Comment: Sobre programação não. O Meta é apenas para assuntos relacionados ao uso e funcionamento do site.

Comment: Talvez vc possa usar o chat para ver se consegue alguma coisa.

Comment: Se existe aqui no meta uma discussão da criação de um novo site*

Comment: Ah tah.. aí eu não sei, acredito que não

Comment: procurei aqui no meta e não achei, então criei uma [discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6899) pra isso da uma olhada e deixa a sua opinião