# criação de pt.talk.stackoverflow.com para discussões relacionadas a programação

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Existem muitas perguntas consideradas baseada em opinião, por que não criar um site especificamente para esses tipos de perguntas algo como *pt.talk.stackoverflow.com*

Sempre que a pergunta é baseada e opinião é dito algo como "fóruns ou blogs seriam mais ideais para esse tipo de pergunta", então por que não criar um fórum/comunidade do SOpt para isso?

Teria algum ponto negativo? Esses pontos negativos suprimiram os pontos positivos?

**edit:**

Sobre já existir o chat - minha opinião é que, o nome mesmo diz, é apenas um chat, você fala o que quer, sobre o que quer, o *pt.talk.stackoverflow.com* seria algo mais "formal", com regras assim como o StackOverflow e o Meta, não seria qualquer pergunta que estaria nos parâmetros desse site, por exemplo, no chat eu faria uma pergunta como "qual layout é melhor?" E passaria dois links dos HTML/CSS ou printscreen, já nesse novo site seria algo mais padronizado, respostas baseadas em opiniões mas com alguma explicação não só "acho X melhor que Y", mas "acho X melhor que Y porque A, B e C", além disso debates que seriam interessantes podem passar dispercebidos e/ou esquecidos no chat

Se um site de perguntas aberto, para perguntas baseadas em opiniões, não for viável talvez um site em que as perguntas fossem feitas por algo similar aos "moderadores" mas com as respostas sendo abertas a todos, com o mesmo padrão de resposta discutido acima. 
Ou então algo como uma eleição, onde as perguntas mais votadas ou escolhidas pelos "moderadores" são abertas,  porém isso pode deixar o site complicado demais. Por exemplo pessoas A, B e C criam/elegem discussões relevantes e as mesmas podem ser respondidas por qualquer participante da comunidade seguindo um determinado padrão, isso impediria discussões de discussões sobre o que é ou não relevante

Comment: Não poderia usar o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para este tipo de dúvida?

Comment: @gato imagino algo mais "formal", no mesmo formato do StackOverflow e do Meta e direcionado para comunidade brasileira

Comment: Já existem o chat, bem como o colega felino comentou, como também o [Stack Underflow](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow/).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não conheço o Stack Underflow. Sobre o chat editei a pergunta falando um pouco mais sobre isso

Comment: @dvd não me importo muito com -1, o importante é criar uma discussão sobre um assunto interessante, independentemente do resultado

Comment: A SE nao levou pra frente nem o SUpt, que seria de grande valia pra toda a comunidade luso-brasileira, imagina algo assim. A SE não se importa com nada que venha da comunidade internacional. Talvez sugerindo no metao voce tenha mais atencao deles, por aqui eles jamais irão ler ou dar importancia.

Comment: @dvd não acredito em perguntas que não valham a pena, apenas em em pessoas que não merecem o meu tempo

Comment: @Articuno não adianta levar algo adiante se nem a própria comunidade não estiver interessada, antes de pedir algo seria melhor montar algo solido e não apenas uma pergunta/idéia

Comment: @dvd não acredito que tiraria o foco SOpt, porque seria para algo diferente da proposta do StackOverflow, um não elimina o outro mas sim complementa a comunidade SE

Comment: Sem desesperança, mas realmente foge ao conceito da SE como um todo. Teve até um ensaio para um site de QA de maternidade/paternidade que conseguia ser absolutamente fantástico (com perguntas do naipe de "qual a sequência correta dos filmes Star Wars que devo apresentar aos meus filhos e por quê?"). Mas não era um formato para promover discussões, era um formato de compartilhamento de experiências. Isso que você fala é um meio termo entre o "terceiro ambiente" (o chat, chamado assim no artigo de divulgação do chat, muito legal por sinal) que seria uma "mesa de bar" e o formato formal...

Comment: ... Então realmente o melhor seria você criar a ferramenta equivalente e talvez até mesmo vender pra SE e ficar rhyko (cheio de letra estranha para dar mais chiqueza). Eles por si dificilmente acatariam sua ideia. Talvez acatassem se fosse para absorver/neutralizar um concorrente, mas não pela ideia em si.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

O motivo do sucesso do Stack Overflow em particular, e do Stack Exchange como um todo, é o formato objetivo das perguntas e respostas. Se você tem um problema real que seja comum, você vem aqui e em geral encontra a solução rapidamente. Esse é o objetivo. Discussões abertas e baseadas em gosto ou critérios vagos não ajudam ninguém a resolver problemas reais.

Se isso ainda não foi suficiente... Existem outros sites que possuem formatos diferentes. De cara consigo pensar nos seguintes:

- Yahoo! Respostas. Essa sucursal do inferno tem [uma sessão destinada a "Programação e Design"](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/dir/index/discover?sid=396545663). As perguntas [ficam bem no padrão que você sugere](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20180312003903AA4OFok), e obviamente as respostas não são da melhor qualidade:

> **OP:** O que faz um designer grafico. Precisa saber desenhar?
>
> **R:** Sim, designer grafico faz aqueles desenhos que vc vê nas revistas, ou ele faz animações.
>
> **R:** Sim, é obrigatório que o designer gráfico saiba desenhar para fazer artes, jogos, esquemas etc
>
> **R:** É claro né seu animal
>
> **R:** Mtntntm

- Existe também o [Quora](https://www.quora.com). O problema do quora é que em geral para cada pergunta você tem algumas redações de exame de faculdade bem detalhadas mas que acabam abordando mais temas do que você queria, seguidas de várias pessoas dizendo exatamente a mesma coisa das formas mais vagas possíveis. E você vai ver muitas, mas muitas abobrinhas. Por exemplo:

[Is Python a dying language? A friend of my grandmother’s is a computer scientist from MIT. He told me that I should not learn Python because it's a dying language, and that I should learn Assembly because it's better than Python.](https://www.quora.com/Is-Python-a-dying-language-A-friend-of-my-grandmother%E2%80%99s-is-a-computer-scientist-from-MIT-He-told-me-that-I-should-not-learn-Python-because-its-a-dying-language-and-that-I-should-learn-Assembly-because-its-better-than-Python)

Tradução livre:

> O Python é uma lingugem moribunda? Um amigo da minha avó [nota do tradutor: não consegui conter o riso] é um cientista da computação do MIT. Ele me disse que eu não deveria aprender Python porque é uma linguagem que está morrendo, e que eu deveria aprender Assembly [mwahahahahahaha] porque é melhor do que Python.

Pergunte-se, honestamente, quanto tempo uma pergunta dessas levaria para ser fechada aqui.

[A resposta que até o momento está votada como a segunda melhor](https://www.quora.com/Is-Python-a-dying-language-A-friend-of-my-grandmother%E2%80%99s-is-a-computer-scientist-from-MIT-He-told-me-that-I-should-not-learn-Python-because-its-a-dying-language-and-that-I-should-learn-Assembly-because-its-better-than-Python/answer/Peter-Johnston) afirma que, possivelmente, o Google já possui um sistema que fará com que nós nunca mais tenhamos que digitar uma linha de código novamente...

> Think Infinite Number of Monkeys with Typewriters and you get the current state of code development. Now imagine when Google creates a program to download and organise GitHub. And scrape every website worldwide. No-one will ever have to write a line of code again. I'll bet they've already done it.

Tradução:

> Pense em uma quantidade infinita de macacos com máquinas de escrever e você terá uma ideia do estado da arte da programação. Agora imagine quando o Google criar um programa para baixar e organizar o Github [Baixar o Github... P... que P...]. E fazer *scraping* de todos os sites da Internet. Ninguém jamais terá que escrever uma linha de código novamente. Eu aposto que já fizeram isso.

Algo que mais parece se encaixar no [stack de Sci Fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com) do que em um site de programação propriamente dito.

- E finalmente existe o [4chan](https://www.4chan.org/), onde você pode perguntar literalmente o que quiser. Se for um pedido de ajuda com programação, talvez o canal /R/ (de request) seja o mais adequado. Cuidado, você verá muita coisa que não quer ver, e provavelmente acenderá alguns alertas nos sistemas da polícia federal.

---

Como você pode ver, a qualidade de uma discussão na internet está ligada ao formato e às regras que são impostos. Há quem ache que o que fazemos aqui é chato, feio e bobo porque nós somos muito rígidos com as nossas regras, mas a alternativa é um mundo onde o ruído é mais forte do que o sinal.

Comment: "Yahoo! Respostas, essa sucursal do inferno [...]" Cara, rachei muito com esse trecho da resposta!! Show

Comment: Excelente resposta! Queria poder votar mais de uma vez, mas o site não deixa infelizmente xD

Comment: Há uns anos atrás (2007, acho) perguntei no Yahoo Respostas como fazer para se ler os valores de uma annotation em Java. A única resposta que recebi e que foi aceita como a melhor pelo voto da comunidade foi "*procura no google*".

Comment: @VictorStafusa ainda falta um fórum que equilibre entre discussões abertas e perguntas regradas